# Issue with a tag height

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want to my tag has exactly the same size as text in it, without any extra spaces in upper  and lower parts like it shows in image (I mean the red rectangle)[image]

this is the markup

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">content</a></li>
</ul>
```

​ 
and this is my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGDuU/10/)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I know is to set the height based on the line-height:

```
li, a {
    line-height: 12px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EGDuU/12/

Comment: No probs, didn't notice you were Armenian also, surname is a giveaway :P

Comment: It nice to meet compatriot here, could you give me any contacts?

Answer (score 1):

That’s possible only by settings that relate to the specific font being used and the specific text content.

If you set text solid, i.e. `line-height: 1`, there is still room above most characters and below most characters. Most Latin letters sit on the text baseline, and there is some room below it, for descenders (and for diacritic marks under a character). On the other hand, some characters, like “j” and “Å” may slightly stretch out of edges of the font height.

For the specific example “content” and for the Arial font, suitable settings would appear to be

```
li { line-height: 0.6; }
a { position: relative; bottom: 0.02em; }
```

Of course, such styling would be very fragile, and making text hit a border tends to reduce legibility and esthetic appearance.